# Google Cloud Storage browser escaping spaces

Tags: google-cloud-storage

This appears to be fairly recent, but previously if I were to click a folder in the Google Cloud Storage web browser, it would take me to the directory even if there were spaces in the directory. The name of the folders in the breadcrumb navigation are showing up as:

`Unknown%20Company`

When previously it would have been:

`Unknown Company`

It seems like this has recently started happening, is there some kind of changelog for the frontend of this application? All the files are still accessible through gsutils if I do something like:

`gsutil ls -a gs://bucket-name/Folder\ Name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've confirmed this is an issue in the GCS UI and is being worked on. I'll post an update here when it has been resolved.

**Update:** As of 2018-05-08 03:12 PDT, the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Seems like it's working now. Thank you so much for the info!